# Flutter how to show percentage type container

Tags: flutter

I need to show this type of line in my flutter app but dont get any idea how ill build this

[image]

If have simple background line now

```
Container(color: Color(0xffABEBC6 ), width: width * 0.7, height: 4,),
```

But i need add this thick dark shade line on that.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a progress indicator?

Comment: It's just a simple container. Need to show that container something like this

Comment: I provided an answer, you can copy that code and paste it right on dartpad.dev to try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Stack Widget which will add container above each other at the same place

```
        Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Color(0xffABEBC6),
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 4,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2, // here you can define your percentage of progress, 0.2 = 20%, 0.3 = 30 % .....
                height: 4,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage()
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double totalWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(children: [
              Container(color: Colors.green[900], height: 4, width: 0.7 * totalWidth),
              Container(color: Color(0xffABEBC6), height: 4, width: 0.3 * totalWidth),

            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want something more dynamic, check out [LinearProgressIndicator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-rhXZLtpv0)